# How to add compiled CSS code to SASS files without CSS file being overwritten

Tags: css, sass

There is currently SASS files in place (mixins, partials, variables etc) however, although these are still in place, a lot of CSS code was manually added to the final compiled CSS file which means the SASS files are not updated and if they were compiled, the manual CSS that was added would be overwritten.

How can I add the manual CSS that was added to the compiled CSS so that it is included as part of my SASS and prevent any overwrites?

Comment: You could simply add it into the SASS files instead of into the compiled CSS file? Or else just create a separate `extra.css` file and load that separately using `<link >` tag.

Comment: The answer depends on whether we're talking SASS syntax or SCSS syntax in your SASS files.

Comment: @Kokodoko but then it is adding an extra HTTP request if i add the CSS file additionally. There is too much CSS code to be adding manually back into the SASS files

Comment: @connexo we are dealing with SASS in this instance

Comment: Why is one extra http request a problem? And why can't you copy>paste the CSS into the SASS file? It was also pasted into the generated css file, so the amount of code is the same.

Comment: @Kokodoko because the SASS file usually compiles all the code into a single CSS file in one request.  There have been some code changes made to the CSS before I started this role so I am worried if I write some SASS code and compile it, the CSS changes that were manually added by the previous developer will be overwritten, causing the site to break

Comment: You can still open the SASS file, and paste your own CSS in there. Then when you compile the SASS, everything will be bundled in one final output. If that causes a problem, you can paste that specific problem here on Stackoverflow. Otherwise it's a bit hard to tell what exactly is going wrong in your project.

Comment: Remember, SCSS is valid CSS. Simply make a new file, copy in your CSS, name it with a SCSS extension and include it in your compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the normal css file part of my SASS so it compiled as one file than to overwrite it. I then setup my own SASS structure which new code will go in to.